# Rectifiers in parallel - mosfet

Tags: mosfet, voltage-regulator, rectifier, brushless-dc-motor, bridge-rectifier

I see the question has been asked a few times about using rectifiers in parallel to get a higher current rating and this is not advisable however I wanted to ask how this would apply to a active mosfet regulator and rectifier namely the fh020aa commonly found in bikes having a peak current of 50 Amps.

My application will generate 120 amps peak and at 12 volts and a standard 3 phases rectifier would lose a lot of that power so I wish to use two of these in parallel with a brushless motor to gain 100 amps peak.

Can it be done? Or is there a more suited rectifier capable of taking the current?

Comment: We could use a few details. A schematic or a drawing of your intended design would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In theory , [this](http://ixapps.ixys.com/Datasheet/MTI200WX75GD.pdf) part can be designed to handle more than two Shindengen **fh020aa** regulators, but it does not include the thermal, mechanical and electrical interface parts added.
[image]

Mind you these external regulators are designed for motor cycle alternators.
Now you can get a 136A 14V alternator with internal 3 phase regulator for less than half the [price](https://www.walmart.com/ip/DB-Electrical-ABO0065-Alternator-Dodge-Durango-2004-04-5-7L-5-7-Ram-Pickup-Truck-2003-2004-2005-2006-03-04-05-06-5-7-5-7L-56028699AA-56029086AA-0-124/145763355).

Comment: The reason for using active rectification or mosfets is fir efficiency my problem is the high current 1.5kw is alot of power and I was hoping to get away without having to build another circuit as I can't seem to find much information on making an actual circuit no one seems to have any diy examples especially not for that current rating.